# Открытие другого сайта на wordpress

Tags: wordpress, openserver, веб-сайт, настройки

Установил `WordPress`. В `OpenServer` отображается целый ряд сайтов

[image: меню OpenServer]

Открыл сайт `myshop.ru`.

[image: Внешний вид сайта myshop.ru]

Попытался изменить сайт на другой в настройках WordPress.

[image: Настройки WordPress]

Попытался в ***Общие настройки -> Название сайта*** ввести названия другого сайта - `digitalshop.ru`. При открытии последнего открылся тот же самый сайт (по крайней мере та же самая тема `Twenty Twenty-One`)

[image: Внешний вид сайта digitalshop.ru]

Подскажите как добиться открытия другого сайта.
При вводе в ***Общие настройки -> Адрес сайта (URL)*** (см. выше настройки WordPress) адреса `http://localhost/wordpress/digitalshop.ru` получаю окно

[image: Не открывающаяся страница]

Comment: Изучаем https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/Как-правильно-перенести-сайт-на-wordpress/

Comment: @SeVlad 1. а что если тот сайт, который я хочу открыть, был сохранен раннее на этом же компьютере (я исправил пользователь и пароль в файле `wp-config.php`). Каким образом открыть такой файл?

Comment: Вернуть всё назад